# How can I drag and drop from Excel cells to a drag-enabled task pane programatically?

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, interop, vsto

I am using Excel 2007, VS2008 Pro.
I am building a VSTO  Add-in that requires "drag and drop from Excel cells to a drag-enabled task pane".

So far I notice that I can only drag and drop within the cells themselves. It does not allow me to drop into the task Pane or drag past the sheet limits.
(http://www.computerimages.com/tip_xl.html)

Note: The task pane has drag drop enabled, I ahve already tested I can drag/drop from task pane to excel but I need to do this the other way around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag-and-drop to custom task pane in Excel VSTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670505/drag-and-drop-to-custom-task-pane-in-excel-vsto)

Answer (score 1):

From the IDE, set `AllowDrop` on the control you want to drop your data on, then wire up the events for `DragOver` and `DragDrop` on that same control.

Your code would look something like this:

```
TextBox TaskPane;

void DragNDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move) {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)) {
      string csvText = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, false).ToString();
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvText)) {
        TaskPane.Text = csvText;
      }
    }
  }
}

void DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)) {
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
  } else {
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
  }
}
```